# emitModelToViewChange not working on ngOnInit

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using emitModelToViewChange to update a formControl display value without updating its raw value on ngOnInit but it displays it.

```
  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this._selectedOptions = [...(this.formControl.value || [])];

    if (this._options.length === this._selectedOptions.length){
      this.formControl.setValue(['Select all', ...this._selectedOptions]);
      this.formControl.setValue(this._selectedOptions, { emitModelToViewChange: false });
    }
  }
```

However, the emitModelToViewChange is not working, it updates the displayed value. I also tested the emitEvent and it is not triggered on ngOnInit.

Answer (score 0):

Please call this logic on `ngAfterViewInit` after the view/form is initialized!

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  template: `
    <input type="text" [formControl]="control" (change)="change()"/>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  control = new FormControl();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.control.valueChanges.subscribe(this.change);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.control.setValue('test', {
      emitModelToViewChange: false,
    });
  }

  change(...args: any) {
    console.log('change', args);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-bsxg6r?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)